# Getting a specified column's value based on the value in another column of the same row?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, select, dataset

I have this SQL Table:

```
TABLE: Info

COLUMNS:|   Name   |  Value
--------|----------|------------------
ROW:    |   Server |  255.255.255.255
ROW:    |   Host   |  212.212.212.212
ROW:    |   User   |  Admin
```

I'm selecting this table like that: `SELECT  * FROM Info`

Now after I got all in this table.

I want to get the value `Where Name = 'Server'` and put it into the `Server` variable.

What is the best method to do it in C#?

DataSet? DataReader? And how can I accomplish this?

---

If you didn't understand what I need here is another good explanation thx to Tim:

*I'm trying to get a specified column's value based on the value in another column of the same row*

Comment: What is your Server variable?  A class?  A string? Are you trying to get a specified column's value based on the value in another column of the same record? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Tim They are both VarChar. & Yes, i'm trying to get a specified column's value based on the value in another column of the same record (row)

Comment: See my comment below your comment to @Kobe

Comment: If I understand right, if you query the table for Name = 'Server', you want to get the Value = '255.255.255.255', right?  If so, see my comment on @Kobe's answer.

Comment: @Tim No your not right, my query is `SELECT * FROM Info`.
And i need to get save '255.255.255.255' inside `string Server`.

Comment: @Danpe...ok, let's see if I finally understand.  You want to be able to pull the value '255.255.255.255' out of the result set from SELECT * FROM Info, based on the Name = 'Server'?  I can give an example for that, but I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just do a WHERE based query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest comments, it appears that you want to get all the rows in the table, and then be able to select a given row based on the Name column.

A DataTable would be best if your program is going to need to access the different rows at different times - as long as the DataTable is in memory/cached, you can pull the value for any name at any time.

If you just need to do it once, a SqlDataReader would probably be faster, but its forward-only.

DataTable example:

Assuming you've already filled the DataTable (name info in the example), you can use the Select method:

```
DataRow[] selectedRows = info.Select("Name = 'Server'");

string serverIP = selectedRows[0]["Value"].ToString();
```

DateReader example:

Based upon @Kobe's code, simply check the Name each time you advance to the next record, and then pull the Value out:

```
bool valueFound = false;

while (reader.Read() && !valueFound)
{
    if (reader["Name"].ToString() == "Server")
    {
       serverIP = reader["Value"].ToString();
       valueFound = true;
    }
 }
```

There are some caveats to be aware of.  First, the Select method of the DataTable returns an array of DataRow, so if more than one record has "Server" in the Name column, you'll get multiple results. If that's by design, that's fine - just loop through the array of DataRows.

Second, if there are a lot of rows in the table, or there is the potential down the road, the reader may be slower depending on where the record of interest is in the table.  And if you're dealing with the possibility of multiple records in the table matching the Name criteria, it's probably easier all around to just stick with a DataTable.

Comment: Thank you :) i'm not using the 'WHERE' clause because i want to get all the info in 1 Command (1 Request) from the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for , if so let me know , i will refine the code with USING key word and remove the sql inline and post you one more answer soon

one more example from google ,

```
// instantiate and open connection
            conn =  new 
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            // don't ever do this!
//          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
//              "select * from Customers where city = '" + inputCity + "'";

            // 1. declare command object with parameter
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);

            // 2. define parameters used in command object
            SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@City";
            param.Value         = inputCity;

            // 3. add new parameter to command object
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            // get data stream
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // write each record
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", 
                    reader["CompanyName"], 
                    reader["ContactName"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // close reader
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            // close connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

other example...

```
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Info where name='+server+'", sqlConn);
    SqlDataReader r = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
    while ( r.Read() ) {
        string name = (string)r["Name"];
        Debug.WriteLine(username + "(" + userID + ")");
    }
    r.Close();
```

Comment: I know how to do that. but i want to get all the values in 1 query.

Comment: If you want all the values from that record, simply add additional lines for each column - i.e. string server = (string)r["Server"]; string host = (string)r["Host"]; etc.  r.Read() advances to the next record in the result set, and you can access every column in that record using the normal C# syntax (r[<columnName> or <columnOrdinal>])

Comment: You still dont get it, check my new explenation.
I dont have a "Server" column, the "Server" is the **VALUE**.

Comment: I get it - I just didn't pick up that Name and Value were column headings in your original post.  My comment above still stands - you can get any value for any column from the current SqlDataReader row - just tell the reader what column you want, either by its name or its ordinal.

Comment: @Tim Can you Add an answer so i can see how can i do it?
I know how to get a coulmn value on a spacific row, but how can i get a diffrent coulmn value on the same row as another spacific coulmn value?

Comment: @Danpe - @Kobe's example will still work (if I understand what you're trying to do now), but where he has string name = (string)r["Name"]; you'll use string value = (string)r["Value"]; - so if 'Server' is the name passed in, the Value will be '255.255.255.255'